# Flatten part of nested object using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am using a library that returns a filtered version of results. The problem is that the results add an additional "item" layer for each object that is in an array which is not the format I need. Note below how both units and depts are wrapped in the "ITEM":{} object. **I want to remove that item layer using just vanilla javascript.**

```
{
  "units": [
    {
      "ITEM": {
        "UnitName": "Unit1",
        "UnitID": 1,
        "depts": [
          {"ITEM": {"DeptName": "Dept1-1"}}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ITEM": {
        "UnitName": "Unit2",
        "UnitID": 2,
        "depts": [
          {"ITEM": {"DeptName": "Dept2-1"}},
          {"ITEM": { "DeptName": "Dept2-2"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to partially flatten this so it looks like the following.

```
{
  "units": [
    {
        "UnitName": "Unit1",
        "UnitID": 1,
        "depts": [
          {"DeptName": "Dept1-1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "Unit2",
        "UnitID": 2,
        "depts": [
          {"DeptName": "Dept2-1"},
          { "DeptName": "Dept2-2"}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Because I will be repeating this for other data, I'm trying to figure out a generic function to remove this extra layer whenever there is an "item" object wrapped around every returned object in an array.
However, every example I can find to flatten a javascript object assumes I want the entire thing flattened. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196695/how-to-flatten-a-object-tree-in-javascript), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803044/deep-flatten-javascript-object-recursively)

I'm sure there has got to be an existing solution already, but I probably need to use another word other than flattening to find the right results. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"I want to remove that item layer using just vanilla javascript."_ - please may you show us how you are trying to do that? Consider adding a [mcve]

Comment: This is not “flattening” which is why you’re having trouble with the googling. This is arguably transforming, but barely that

Comment: @Adam Got it! I figured I was using the wrong term so thanks for giving me another search term to try when/if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can recursively traverse the object tree and clean up:

```js
// traverses the object tree and replaces `{ ITEM: ??? }` with the `???`
function removeITEM(item) {
  if (typeof item !== "object" || item === null) return item;

  if (Array.isArray(item)) return item.map(removeITEM);

  // that's where the cleanup happens
  if (item.ITEM) return removeITEM(item.ITEM);

  let copy = {};
  for (let key in item) {
    copy[key] = removeITEM(item[key]);
  }
  return copy;
}

console.log(removeITEM({
  "units": [
    {
      "ITEM": {
        "UnitName": "Unit1",
        "UnitID": 1,
        "depts": [
          { "ITEM": { "DeptName": "Dept1-1" } }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ITEM": {
        "UnitName": "Unit2",
        "UnitID": 2,
        "depts": [
          { "ITEM": { "DeptName": "Dept2-1" } },
          { "ITEM": { "DeptName": "Dept2-2" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Or maybe an alternative: If you have access to the JSON string *(like from a ajax request)* it may be an option to clean the data structure up on `JSON.parse()`:

```js
const json = '{"units":[{"ITEM":{"UnitName":"Unit1","UnitID":1,"depts":[{"ITEM":{"DeptName":"Dept1-1"}}]}},{"ITEM":{"UnitName":"Unit2","UnitID":2,"depts":[{"ITEM":{"DeptName":"Dept2-1"}},{"ITEM":{"DeptName":"Dept2-2"}}]}}]}';

console.log(JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => (value && value.ITEM) ?? value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: This solved my issue and was also reusable. Thanks so much from a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign and map on array to achieve that:

```
data = Object.assign(data, {
  "units": data.units
    .map((u) => Object.assign(u.ITEM, {
       "depts": u.ITEM.depts
         .map((d) => d.ITEM) 
    }))
});
```

Comment: This was a really nice compact way of solving the issue for this particular data structure. I awarded points to the other one though because it was reusable for other results I might get. Thanks so much for the help!